# javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[11,3] in jboss-web.xml

Tags: xml, jboss-eap-6

I am using Java 1.6 and JBoss EAP 6.1.

My application runs on JBoss 5.1, but when I try to run my application on JBoss 6.1, I get this error:

```
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[11,3] in jboss-web.xml
```

JBoss's log:

```
00:06:52,823 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "MyApplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name: "MyApplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")
00:06:54,743 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."MyApplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."MyApplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "MyApplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war"

Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS018014: Failed to parse XML descriptor "/content/MyApplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml" at [11,3]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.JBossWebParsingDeploymentProcessor.deploy(JBossWebParsingDeploymentProcessor.java:79)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:120) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        ... 5 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[11,3]
Message: Unexpected element 'class-loading' encountered
        at org.jboss.metadata.parser.util.MetaDataElementParser.unexpectedElement(MetaDataElementParser.java:109)
        at org.jboss.metadata.parser.jbossweb.JBossWebMetaDataParser.parse(JBossWebMetaDataParser.java:206)
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.JBossWebParsingDeploymentProcessor.deploy(JBossWebParsingDeploymentProcessor.java:71)
        ... 6 more

00:06:54,748 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 8) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "MyApplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"MyApplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".PARSE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"MyApplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment \"MyApplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS018014: Failed to parse XML descriptor \"/content/MyApplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml\" at [11,3]
    Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[11,3]
Message: Unexpected element 'class-loading' encountered"}}
00:06:54,867 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment MyApplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war (runtime-name: MyApplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war) in 118ms
```

I'm getting this exception in `jboss-web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>

    <!--   <context-root>MyApplication</context-root>
    <class-loading java2ClassLoadingCompliance="false">
        <loader-repository>com.globalss:loader=MyApplication.war
            <loader-repository-config>java2ParentDelegation=false</loader-repository-config>
        </loader-repository> 
    </class-loading>-->

    <class-loading java2ClassLoadingCompliance="false">
        <loader-repository>
            org.myapp:loader=MyApplication.war
            <loader-repository-config>java2ParentDelegation=false
            </loader-repository-config>
       </loader-repository>
    </class-loading>
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>database</res-ref-name>
        <jndi-name>java:/database</jndi-name>
    </resource-ref>
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>dataSource</res-ref-name>
        <jndi-name>java:/dataSource</jndi-name>
    </resource-ref>
</jboss-web>
```

Why do we get this error?

What is the root cause of getting this error?

How do we solve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/167108?tstart=0) JBoss's community thread, the error is occurring because the tag `class-loading` is no longer present on JBoss EAP 6.X (JBoss AS 7.X) [*jboss-web.xml* schema](https://github.com/jboss/metadata/blob/master/web/src/main/resources/schema/jboss-web_7_2.xsd).

The reason that tag is no longer present is because

> *Class loading has changed from **hierarchical** to **modular** in AS7. (...) The behaviour that this provokes in EAP 5 is now the default class-loading  behaviour in AS 7.*

The solution passes by commenting

> *the <class-loading> element in jboss-web.xml, since it is no longer necessary.*

Comment: It was working in `Jboss 6.1` So I was trying to deploy in `Oracle weblogic 10.3.6` so I added another file called `weblogic.xml` and i was ablle to deploy in weblogic. but now its not working in `Jboss6.1` Though I have removed `weblogic.xml` file.

Comment: any ways I will try What u have suggested